# How to tel Firebase to expire/renew clients token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new in firebase and I want to tel Firebase to renew/expire all clients token for security issues from my server.
Or any solution to meet this need.

Comment: Frank, would FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() be sufficient (you'd need to have a registered FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener which will be notified when the operation completes)?

Comment: You mean when I call this  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() in my server all tokens get expire/renew?

Comment: i assume they will be expired, to renew you need to redo your authnetication flow, whatever that may be on your server (you probably have a special server email/password acct).  I just found this as well> // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
            }
        });

Comment: Read the end of this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users perhaps that helps you. I'm not sure if it's suitable for a server environment...

Comment: there are also these articles on integrating google app engine backend with firebase, you may find more information there as well (though i see they haven't been renewed the way the firebase client ones have) https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services If you find this helpful i can shove it in an answer